# How do I return related models over RESTful API using loopbackjs?

Tags: ember.js, loopbackjs

I am evaluating loopback as the API server for a new project. I need to return data in a format specific to Ember and I need to return either: an array of IDs to related models, or an embedded array of the related models objects.

I have experimented with using the Include filter to automatically include the related models (using hasMany relationship type). When we do basic performance testing we find that the include filter adds a significant performance penalty.

What is the best performing method for getting access to the related models?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have category that hasMany products.

To get products, related to category, request the `/api/category/:id/products` endpoint.

Also you can use [limit](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Limit+filter) and [fields](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Fields+filter) filter for better performance.

Comment: Thanks, but that is for the Angular SDK. I'm trying to work with Ember. there is currently no Ember SDK :-(

Comment: Ah, I missed it, sorry! I totally updated the answer.

Comment: we had a limit of 30 records and specified the fields we wanted. as an example of how bad it is, we wrote our own query logic for find() that includes related models. avg 310ms for ours, avg 2400ms for native code. as in 2.4 SECONDS to return the first 30 records.

Comment: Good, please create an issue or perform a pull request in DB connector repo to improve it!

Comment: @MarkL, BTW, what kind of connector do you use?

Comment: we are using the postgresql connector.